# Why the output is returning none type

Tags: python

Below is the code. the main() test is suppose to return greatest common divisor but it is returning None type. Not understanding the return calls issue in gcd

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def gcd(self):
        p = self._gcd(self._x, self._y)
        return p

    def _gcd(self, x, y):
        if (x % y == 0):
            return y
        else:
             _gcd(y, x%y)


def main():
    f = Fraction(6,4)
    return f.gcd()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (main())
```

Comment: the `else` clause in `_gcd` doesn't return anything, so if the function can end without a `return`, which returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in the `else` case, so you get a return type of `None`. Change the recursion call:

`_gcd(y, x%y)`

to

`return self._gcd(y, x%y)`